# get flickr private images by API

Tags: php, flickr

Does anyone knows, if I can get my private images from flickr, using flickr API.
I need to get my private flickr images using the API,

What I'm trying to do is to create a password protected flickr Set, for my website.

In the application I'm gonna get the images from flickr, which are in a private set, I'll share a username and password with my friends, then, when they authenticate into my website they will be able to see my private flickr images.

Answer (score 3):

You need to authenticate as a user (who is the owner of the private pictures): http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.howto.web.html.

Comment: I'm the ovner of the private pictures.

Comment: Then you simply authenticate through the Flickr API with your credentials.

Comment: I think I couldn't explain the problem, I want my friends, who are authenticated to my personal website, to view my private images on flickr, using my credentials, without seeing them. So I should hardcode my credentials to a flickr request.

Comment: Yes, you should do that. But make sure you make the request from your server, not the browser!